# Google Map zoom level with markers from xml file

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I hope that you can help with my problem ;)
I'm using google maps api and jquery to load markers dynamically from xml file. Everything works as I expected, except of one thing. Map looses zoom level when I load the second set of markers. Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://markilfin.lx10.net/) Try to click button under the map, then try to click the second button. And you will understand what I mean.  Here is my [js code](http://markilfin.lx10.net/js/markers.js).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is with `MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);`, because you only add new point to bounds.

For start in your function MYMAP.placeMarkers() you must clear bounds.
<del>`MYMAP.bounds = new GLatLngBounds();`</del>

Correct is

```
MYMAP.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Comment: Ahh. Correct is MYMAP.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();